# How to get HERE indoor positioning sdk to run properly?

Tags: android, here-api, here-maps-rest

I tried following the steps to run the indoor positioning example from:
https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/positioning-venues-and-logging

Upon running the app, it get's stuck on "Waiting for position fix" screen. How can I resolve this problem?

[image]
Furthermore, what should I be replacing the intent name be to get the information described on the installation guide that the example app should be supplying
"The application shows the following:
• Location in Latitude and Longitude coordinates. If possible, verify that these match with your test site
location.

• Position indicator on a map

• The floor level

• The building ID

• Location type is "INDOOR"

Answer (score 0):

To remove the stuck "Waiting for position fix", you have to enable/turn on the GPS on your Android phone. This will enable the App to use the Location Service of your phone.

Also, the value of the intent name is just a custom string of your choice.

Regarding your last questions, the app shows, in addition to the position indicator of the map:

- Position source,
- Position technology,
- Latitude and Longitude of location,
- Altitude,
- Speed and
- Uncertainty